# Trouble getting the correct wildcard match in the middle of a string

Tags: python, string, search

I'm having some trouble getting a correct wildcard match in the middle of a string. I was using the the if statement below and it works. I started running the script searching through about 500 files and discovered some of them have "random" characters (upper or lower) and/or numbers between name & {name} for example nameAB234janet or namec123bryce or nothing between them. I tried adding * between them and also tried using re.search for quite a while but nothing is matching now so I'm not getting it right. Any help would be great at this point.

```
if f"name{name} " in line.lower():
```

Comment: If I could add a little more information. I do struggle with match patterns. This one is a string + random characters + variable name + a space plus and trying to make it all lowercase (or possible ignore case?). It was matching partial matches of names that are similar but adding the space at the end after the variable name took care of that. I can add the script if it helps to see it as a whole. It's not to long around 30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I used regex and this worked well. It was also able to give me more accurate matches. Using the re.IGNORECASE to compare worked great without modifying the data as I was before. Maybe it will be useful to someone.

**EDIT 1:** Added \s+ to include more than one space or tabs.

```
if re.search(rf"\s+\"{name}\",", line, re.IGNORECASE):
```